# How to know if content was added to a SharePoint list or folder?

Tags: web-services, spservices, updatelistitems

I'm using the GetListItemChangesSinceToken service in order to be notified for changes in a sharepoint list.

This works ok for deleted items since the ChangeType return Delete , but for added items, apparently there is no ChangeType for that action.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc264031(v=office.14).aspx

Does anybody knows if there is a way to know if content was added to a list or folder using a SharePoint service?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I presume your talking about alerts, setting an alert on a list will notify the selected user by email if you add or edit or delete or all of them ;)

by the sharepoint UI:

http://www.hosting.com/support/sharepoint-2010/create-an-alert-for-a-list-or-library

someone has done it for you already by code:

```
using (SPSite mySiteCollection = new SPSite("http://myserver/myspsite"))
{     
    using (SPWeb mySite = mySiteCollection.OpenWeb(mySiteCollection.RootWeb.ID))
    {

       string myUserLogin = @"MyDomain\MyUser";
       SPUser myUser = mySite.Users[myUserLogin];
       SPAlert newAlert = myUser.Alerts.Add();
       newAlert.Title = "My Title";

       SPListItem myListItem = mySite.Lists["My List Name"].Items.GetItemById(1);
       newAlert.AlertType = SPAlertType.Item;
       newAlert.Item = myListItem;

       newAlert.AlertTemplate = myListItem.ParentList.AlertTemplate;

       newAlert.EventType = SPEventType.Add;

       newAlert.Filter = string.Empty;

       newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;

       newAlert.Update(true);

    }
}
```

each step is outlined in detail here:

http://sharepointlive.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/how-to-create-sharepoint-alerts-for.html

hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I was not talking about alerts. On the other hand, maybe this can solve my problem, since apparently there is no way to know if new items was added to a list or folders using the GetListItemChangesSinceToken service. I will give it a try and provide feedback if there is no way to do it using the specified service.